# Bash: Extract number of filenames to move into the correct directories numbered

Tags: regex, string, bash, extract

I have a list of files in a single directory such as..

```
LDI_P1800-id1.0200.bin
LDI_P1800-id2.0200.bin
...
LDI_P1800-id17.0200.bin
LDI_P1800-id18.0200.bin
...
...
LDI_P1800-id165.0200.bin
LDI_P1800-id166.0200.bin
...
```

and I want to move each of them into directory

```
LDI_P1800-id165.0200.bin to ../id165/.
LDI_P1800-id166.0200.bin to ../id166/.
LDI_P1800-id167.0200.bin to ../id167/.
...
```

and so on.

My guess is that I have to use regular expression to extract id from a string

```
for file in *.0200.bin ; do
    "extracting id from each file"
    mv $file ../id$id/.
done
```

can any body give me help? Thank you!!

Comment: Did you try `rename` method?

Answer (score 6):

Try the following pure-bash solution:

```
for file in *.0200.bin
do
    id=${file#*-}      # delete everything upto the first hyphen
    id=${id%%.*}        # delete everything after the first dot
    [[ ! -d ../$id ]] && mkdir ../$id       # if the directory doesn't exist create it
    mv $file ../$id
done
```

It can also be done in `sed`, but I would prefer the first approach:

```
for file in *.0200.bin
do
    id=$(sed 's/[^-]*-\([^\.]*\).*$/\1/g' <<< $file)
    mkdir -p ../$id && mv $file ../$id
done
```

Comment: I always forget substring removal. Plus One.

Comment: `mkdir` is a *fork* while `[ -d ../$id]` is not! So *don't use `-p` if not needed*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions (not just pattern matching) in `bash` as well.

```
for f in *.0200.bin; do
    [[ $f =~ id[0-9]+ ]] && mv -- "$f" ../${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
done
```

`BASH_REMATCH` is an array that holds the result of the most recent `=~` match. The 0th element contains the string that matches the entire regular expression. Non-zero indices hold the result matched by the *n*th parenthesized group in the regular expression, if any.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to retrieve that id, one is using the following:

```
ID=$(echo $file | grep -o "id[[:digit:]]*\." | cut -b3- | tr -d '.')
```

It uses grep to isolate the `id[DIGITS].` expression, then cuts the `id` part of it and finally removes the `.` character using `tr`

In fact, you can isolate the whole `id[DIGITS]` part and use it in your loop like this:

```
for file in *.0200.bin ; do
    echo "extracting id from each file"
    ID=$(echo $file | grep -o "id[[:digit:]]*\." | tr -d '.')
    mv $file ../$ID/.
done
```

**Update**: As @dogbane suggested, it could be simplified much further to:

```
for file in *.0200.bin ; do
    echo "extracting id from each file"
    ID=$(grep -o "id[[:digit:]]*" <<< $file)
    mv $file ../$ID/.
done
```

Comment: Not sure why you are matching the dot with `grep` and then deleting it with `tr`. I think it could be simplified to: `ID=$(grep -o "id[[:digit:]]*" <<< $file)`